# Not able to get clear understanding of intersect in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table `managers_temp` as:

[image]

I used the intersect method as:

```
select id,name,age from ot.managers_temp
intersect 
select id,name,age from ot.managers_temp
```

As I have understood intersect gives the common data of two tables:

[image]

But when I applied that query then I got the output as:

[image]

When I applied that query instead to get the common data,I am getting the data except the duplicate data.Since,intersect gives the common data,but why here the data is coming except the common data?I am getting confused here,since my expected output was:

```
1 ashwin 21
4 saman  21
```

These two are common data but its showing me data except all common elements? why is this happening so?

Comment: It is giving expected output as intersect gave you output which is common on both table and then distinct on it. It removed one record of ashwin as there is 2 records which passed intersect but then distinct applied on it which removed one of them.

Comment: Why did you only expect those two rows? Perhaps the results would be clearer if you used two different tables rather than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment.

This query

```
select id,name,age from ot.managers_temp
intersect 
select id,name,age from ot.managers_temp
```

Is same as

```
select distinct id,name,age from ot.managers_temp
```

So output is as expected because `intersect` gives common data and then do `distinct` on it but in your case all the records are common as both the tables in `intersect` are the same.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle INTERSECT operator compares the result of two queries and returns the distinct rows that are output by both queries.

See https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-intersect/